# Creating a function to initialise multiple dictionaries with defaultlist()?

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

Just a general question....

I need to initialise at least 50 different dictionaries, which then goes as one of the arguments for a function (make_somefunction) I made that involves returning a dictionary with customised keys and a list as values

Is there a way to initialise a dictionary and output it directly to the function?

Something like this?

```
from collections import defaultdict

def initialise(dict):
       dict =defaultdict(list)
       return (dict)


initialise(dict).make_somefunction(dict, custom_keys, custom_listofvalues)
```

Instead of

```
dict1 = defaultdict(list)
dict2 = defaultdict(list)
dict2 = defaultdict(list)
...
dict49 = defaultdict(list)
dict50 = defaultdict(list)
```

which would individually go as an argument creating different  customised dictionaries

```
make_somefunction(dict1, animals, foods)
make_somefunction(dict2, patients, drugs)
...
make_somefunction(dict50, fridge, fruits)
```

Comment: You mean `make_somefunction(initialise(dict))`?

Comment: Probably? Sorry - I'm new to python. Still trying to get my head around the use of functions.

Comment: do you want to send all 50 dicts in one call to your function ?
Does your function creates a new dict or updates the dict passed to it as an argument?
you might wanna rather just create the dict in your function!

Comment: Hi greenlantern, I've updated my question. RE: your question - no, I don't want to send all 50 dictionaries in one call as the function creates a new dictionary with customised keys and values each time. I did try to initialise the dict into my function, i.e ```def make_somefunction(dict, custom_keys, custom_listofvalues): dict=defaultdict(list) ``` but it gave an error saying ``dict``` needs to be defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a list of the defaultdicts by using a list comprehension.

```
make_somefunction([defaultdict() for i in range(50)])
```

By the way, read the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/index.html) to get a better understanding of python.

Comment: Thanks Roofi for the reply. Is there a way to make it more interactive and not send all 50 dicts at once as each dictionary would have customised keys and values? I've updated my question - hopefully it makes sense. RE: python docs - thank you - I have started reading but still get a bit confused.